# Intel TBB computational graph: how to specify input queue capacity of the node

Tags: c++, tbb, tpl-dataflow, dataflow, tbb-flow-graph

I'm looking for C++ analog of .NET TPL Dataflow library.

In TPL Dataflow you can specify parallelism & blocks' capacity options. If the size of the block's input queue reaches it's capacity then the execution of the producer of the corresponding block is suspended:

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 10 });

var producer = new Task(() => { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        buffer.Post(i);
    }
});

var fstAction = new TransformBlock<int, int>(async (i) => {
    return i*i;
}, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, BoundedCapacity = 10);

var sndAction = new ActionBlock<int>(async (i) => {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, BoundedCapacity = 10);

buffer.LinkTo(fstAction, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
fstAction.LinkTo(sndAction, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

sndAction.Completition.Wait();
```

And I need similar functionality in C++. TBB seems a good choise but I cannot find how to specify the capacity on `function_node`/`buffer_node`. Here is an an example:

```
std::size_t exportConcurrency = 16;
std::size_t uploadConcurrency = 16;

flow::graph graph;

std::size_t count = 1000;
std::size_t idx = 0;

flow::source_node<std::vector<std::string>> producerNode(graph, [&count, &idx](auto& out) {
    out = { "0"s };
    return ++idx != count;
});

flow::function_node<std::vector<std::string>, std::string> exportNode(graph, exportConcurrency, [](auto& ids) {
    return "0"s;
});

flow::function_node<std::string, std::string> uploadNode(graph, uploadConcurrency, [](auto& chunk) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    return "0"s;
});

flow::make_edge(producerNode, exportNode);
flow::make_edge(exportNode, uploadNode);

graph.wait_for_all();
```

Comment: It seems that TBB Flow Graph does not have direct interface to specify buffer's capacity. However, it might be that your problem could be solved differently using TBB. In order to weigh several variants could you please provide more info regarding the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

One can find in the [official docs](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/main/title_main.html), that there are three recommended ways to [limiting resource consumption](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#tbb_userguide/Concurrent_Queue_Classes.html), and one of them is [using `limiter_node`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#tbb_userguide/Concurrent_Queue_Classes.html):

> One way to limit resource consumption is to use a `limiter_node` to set a limit on the **number of messages** that can flow through a given point in your graph.

It not the exact thing that you want, but still should be investigating. Also I was able to find the [concurrent queue classes](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#tbb_userguide/Concurrent_Queue_Classes.html) sections, which can be used with bounded capacity with `set_capacity` method. Maybe you can manage it out that way. Hope this helps.